# How to change font type, font size and bold text in Android style (PopUpMenu)

Tags: android, layout

How do I change things like font size, font type and bold text in a PopUpMenu?

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

I'm doing like this to add this style:

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.AddEffectsStyle);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, binding.btnAddEffect);
```

I tried adding, for example:

```
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

but text won't turn bold.

How do I change thee things I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```html
<style name="YOURSTYLE" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
</style>
```

And for your java:

```js
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.YOURSTYLE);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view);
popup.inflate(R.menu.main_menu);
popup.show();
```

Works perfectly for me.

[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa6AX.png)